# spring transaction management : Read uncommitted data in same transaction

Tags: spring, spring-jdbc

How to read uncommitted data within same transaction . I'm using spring jdbc.

Sample code :

```
 @Transactional
    public Resource update(){
    dao.update();
    Resource resource = dao.getById("1");
    return resource;
    }
```

This is returning the old data since the transaction is not committed yet. I want something similar to entityManager.merge() in JPA. I read some posts about transaction isolation but they all talk about two different transaction. My question is within same transaction how to read uncommitted data ?

Comment: Hi, I encountered the same problem, is there a solution? PLEASE

Comment: Hi, did you found a solution to this, I too need this, please...

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the transaction isolation level

```
@Transactional(isolation=Isolation.READ_UNCOMMITTED)
```

In your case you don't have only one transaction. It looks that you have one transaction for update, one for save. 
If you are using spring data jpa, every CRUD operation is executed in a different transaction.

Comment: Hi, I have @Transactional annotation on my service method only , not on dao. Also i think marking @Transactional(isolation=Isolation.READ_UNCOMMITTED) on my service method will open up the method for other transactions to read uncommitted data which i do not want. My question is can read the uncommitted data in the same single transaction. Am i missing something here?

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
@Transactional
public Resource update(){
  dao2 = dao.update();
  Resource resource = dao2.getById("1");
  return resource;
}
```